# Thread vs. Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

What's the difference between the `threading` and `thread` modules in Python?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

In Python 3, `thread` has been renamed to `_thread`. It is infrastructure code that is used to implement `threading`, and normal Python code shouldn't be going anywhere near it.

`_thread` exposes a fairly raw view of the underlying OS level processes. This is almost never what you want, hence the rename in Py3k to indicate that it is really just an implementation detail.

`threading` adds some additional automatic accounting, as well as several convenience utilities, all of which makes it the preferred option for standard Python code.

Note: as mentioned in [Jeril's alternate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55355799/597742), when considering the use of threads in Python for execution of background tasks, also take a look at `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` as an even higher level API than `threading`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Answer (score 38):

`threading` is just a higher level module that interfaces `thread`.

See here for the `threading` docs:

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

Answer (score 12):

If I'm not mistaken, `thread` allows you to run a *function* as a separate thread, whereas with `threading` you <s>have to</s> create a *class*, but get more functionality.

EDIT: This is not precisely correct. `threading` module provides different ways of creating a thread:

- `threading.Thread(target=function_name).start()`
- Create a child class of `threading.Thread` with your own `run()` method, and start it

Answer (score 0):

There is another one library in Python which can used for threading and works perfectly.

The library called [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html). This makes our work easier.

It has for [thread pooling](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) and [Process pooling](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor).

The following gives an insight:

**ThreadPoolExecutor Example**

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

**Another example**

```
import concurrent.futures
import math

PRIMES = [
    112272535095293,
    112582705942171,
    112272535095293,
    115280095190773,
    115797848077099,
    1099726899285419]

def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for number, prime in zip(PRIMES, executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)):
            print('%d is prime: %s' % (number, prime))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -2):

The module "Thread" treats a thread as a function, while the module "threading" is implemented in an object oriented way, i.e. every thread corresponds to an object.