# Why is there no output using multi-threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I'm reading Programming Python 4th Edition.

Following are the codes(Python3.2):

```
import _thread

def action(i):
    print(i ** 32)

class Power:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def action(self):
        print(self.i ** 32)

_thread.start_new_thread(action,(2,))
_thread.start_new_thread((lambda: action(2)), ())

obj = Power(2)
_thread.start_new_thread(obj.action,())
```

When I run it, there is no output on screen:

```
$python3 thread-example.py
$
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 1):

When the main thread exits, the entire process exits.

You will need to make the main thread wait until the other threads complete.  There is no provision for this in the `_thread` API (it's so low-level).

You can use `threading.Thread.join()`, if you're willing to use a better API.

Answer (score 1):

The underscore `_` means that it is a private API (`thread` module had been obsolete since 2005); you should use `threading` module instead:

```
from threading import Thread

# ...
Thread(target=action, args=[2]).start()
Thread(target=lambda: action(2)).start()
Thread(target=obj.action).start()
```

You don't need to call `.join()` method explicitly; non-daemon threads are joined automatically before the main thread exits.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `threading` module (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5568555/155813))? In your example the main thread exits before child threads can print anything. For example, if you add the following at the end of your example, works on my system:

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

But still you can't guarantee that main thread will not exit  before all child threads exits in more complicated cases. You have following choices:

- Set flags from each child thread and keep checking the flags from main thread before exiting (bad approach).
- Use [`time.sleep`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) to sleep for maximum time all child threads can take to exit (also a bad approach).
- Use [`threading.Thread.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) to wait until each child exits (good approach). (as evident from other answers)