# A function not executing while threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I created two modules which had some functions in them. I enclosed 2 functions in a single function in module1 and imported module1 in module2, The function `often1` enclosed in compiler does'nt seem to execute.

MODULE 1

```
import time,thread

def class_often():
    while 1<2:
        time.sleep(5)
        print "Custom funtion not often runs."

def class_often1():
    while 1<2:
        time.sleep(2)
        print "Custom funtion often runs."

def compiler():
    class_often()
    class_often1()
```

MODULE2

```
import time,d,thread

def often():
    while 1<2:
        time.sleep(2)
        print "funtion not often runs."

def often1():
    while 1<2:
        time.sleep(2)
        print "Function often runs."

thread.start_new_thread(often,())
thread.start_new_thread(often1,())
thread.start_new_thread(d.compiler,())
```

Comment: why don't you use the [threading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568555/thread-vs-threading) module?

Answer (score 2):

You start  compiler in a thread but it calls `class_often` which blocks as it is an infinite loop so the second function cannot get called:

```
def compiler():
    class_often() # blocks
    class_often1()
```

You would need to `thread.start_new_thread` in `d.complier` also i.e:

```
def class_often():
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Custom funtion not often runs.")


def class_often1():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Custom funtion often runs.")


def compiler():
    thread.start_new_thread(class_often,())
    class_often1()
```

Which after changing will give you output like:

```
funtion not often runs.
Custom funtion often runs.
Function often runs.
Custom funtion not often runs.
funtion not often runs.
Custom funtion often runs.
Function often runs.
funtion not often runs.
Custom funtion often runs.
Function often runs.
funtion not often runs.
Custom funtion often runs.
Function often runs.
...........................
```

The [threading lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#module-threading) is also recommended over the `thread` lib.