# Threading issue in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

```
import time
import thread
import termios
import sys
import datetime


try:
    from msvcrt import getch  # try to import Windows version
except ImportError:
    def getch():   # define non-Windows version
        import tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

def tm():

    char = None

    def keypress():
        count=0
        while count<5:
            a=time.time()
            global char
            char = getch()
            b=time.time()
            c=b-a       
            c=c*10000000000000000
            c=int (c)       
            c=c%1000            
            print c
            count+=1



    thread.start_new_thread(keypress, ())

    while True:
        '''if char is not None:
            print("Key pressed is " + char.decode('utf-8'))
            break'''
        print("Program is running")
        time.sleep(5)

thread.start_new_thread(tm ())
```

when I run the code as shown above, it happily does what it's meant to do, which is measure the time in between keystrokes and give the 3 least significant numbers in the measurement.

However, when I take out this part (because I don't need nor necessarily want it there):

```
while True:
        '''if char is not None:
            print("Key pressed is " + char.decode('utf-8'))
            break'''
        print("Program is running")
        time.sleep(5)
```

It breaks. I get the following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "randgen.py", line 50, in <module>
    thread.start_new_thread(tm ())
TypeError: start_new_thread expected at least 2 arguments, got 1
```

***Update***

when I add a comma to the `thread.start_new_thread(tm, ())` I get this error:

`Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr`

However, when the comma is missing, it runs fine as long as that piece of `while True` code is there.

Comment: The reason it "works" without the comma is because you are executing `tm` before calling `thread.start_new_thread` which enters the non-breaking `while True:` loop. If you don't need `tm` to run on another thread, simply call it like `tm()` instead of using `thread.start_new_thread(tm, ())`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `threading` instead of `thread` The `thread` module is a low-level interface to starting threads, and it's going to require a lot of unnecessary headaches while you're learning this. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568555/thread-vs-threading)

Then, the proper way to start a thread would be

```
import threading
import time

def printstuff(stuff):
    while 1:
        print(stuff)
        time.sleep(3)

t = threading.Thread(target=printstuff, args=('helloworld',))
t.start()

# Here is where your main thread will do whatever
print('Main thread running')
time.sleep(5)
print('Main thread done')

# At this point the main thread will be done
# but printstuff will still be printing stuff. 
# Control-c will exit the second thread, and 
# youll be back at a prompt
```

Your code above is not a minimal example, and it's very hard to understand what you're actually trying to accomplish. Try clarifying the goal in some pseudo-code, and then I can work with you to improve your understanding of multi-threading.

Answer (score 2):

#### Separate Thread

If you truly intend to run `tm` in a separate thread, you are missing a comma between your two positional arguments. It should read as follows:

```
thread.start_new_thread(tm, ())
```

#### Main Thread

If you do not need the execution of `tm` to happen in another thread, simple call the function in the current thread like so:

```
tm()
```

This is happening already without the comma since the space is removed by the Python interpreter.

```
thread.start_new_thread(tm ())
# gets turned into
thread.start_new_thread(tm())
# which evaluates tm() before calling 'start_new_thread'
```

If the loop is removed, the return value of `tm()` gets passed as a single argument to `start_new_thread` which results in the original error posted.

#### Threading

As mentioned in the other answer, you likely should be using the `threading` library instead of `thread`. [More details about why are listed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568555/thread-vs-threading)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. but that raises another question, why does it work when that while True statement is there?

Comment: Because the line was never executed. `while True` is an infinite loop. :-)

Comment: @phd The thing is, it does, in fact, execute everything as long as that `while True` loop is there, but when I take it out, the code breaks.

Comment: @alex When you remove the comma, you are **executing** the `tm` function, and passing the result into `start_new_thread`, the space between `tm` and `()` gets removed so it does: `start_new_thread(tm())` which execute the body of `tm`, including the `while True:` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using Python 2.7, here is another example.

```
import thread
import threading

class PeriodicThread(threading._Timer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        threading._Timer.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.finished.clear()
            self.finished.wait(self.interval)
            if not self.finished.isSet():
                self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            else:
                return
            self.finished.set()

class PeriodicThreadManager(object):
    periodic_threads = []
    def run(self, interval, callback_fn, args=[], kwargs={}):
        new_thread = PeriodicThread(interval, callback_fn, args, kwargs)
        self.periodic_threads.append(new_thread)
        thread.start_new_thread(new_thread.run, ())

    def stop_all(self):
        for t in self.periodic_threads:
            t.cancel()
        self._event.set()
    
class YourApplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.threads = PeriodicThreadManager()
        self.threads.run( .01, self.periodic_callback_1 ) # 10 ms but ...
        self.threads.run( .01, self.periodic_callback_2 )

    def periodic_callback_1(self):
        ....

    def periodic_callback_2(self):
        ....
```