# Running python in the background, need to take user input first

Tags: python, linux

I have written some code that I would like to run in the background as it is very time consuming (on the order of hours). I would normally run

```
python3 program_name.py >> output.log &
```

However the first steps of the program take user input. Is there a way to take user input and then run in the background if I close the terminal?

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641094/how-to-accept-input-from-stdin-in-background-while-program-is-running

Comment: Use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html) and pass user input at command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to accept input from stdin in background while program is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641094/how-to-accept-input-from-stdin-in-background-while-program-is-running)

Comment: Take a look at daemonize https://github.com/thesharp/daemonize

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like Tmux and detach and then re-attach when needed.

[Tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux)