# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' in a client file of "Rock, paper, scissors" game

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, pygame

The code above is a simple "Rock, paper, scissors" game

I have just finished the last tutorial from [this](https://youtu.be/XGf2GcyHPhc?t=20275) video. I've tested the code and it is working properly when I open the server and the clients on the same laptop, but as the guy from the Tutorial said it should be able to run from other computers I tried to open a client from my sister's laptop with the server running on mine.
It didn't work, the error I get is: "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' ".

P. S. The beginning of the video explains how the game is supposed to work. And most of the comments are not important, i just write them for taking notes on the code (things I might not remember later on)

Here it is a screenshot of the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAWjc.jpg)

### client.py file:

```py
import pygame
from network import Network
pygame.font.init()

width = 700
height = 700
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Client')

class Button:
    def __init__(self, text, x, y, color):
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y 
        self.color = color
        self.width = 150
        self.height = 100
    
    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 40)
        text = font.render(self.text, 1, (255,255,255))
        win.blit(text, (self.x + round(self.width/2) - round(text.get_width()/2), self.y + round(self.height/2) - round(text.get_height()/2) ))

    def click(self, clicked_position):
        x1 = clicked_position[0]
        y1 = clicked_position[1]

        if self.x <= x1 <= self.x + self.width and self.y <= y1 <= self.y +self.height:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def redraw_window(win, game, player):
    win.fill((128,128,128))
    
    if not(game.connected()):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
        text = font.render('Waiting for Player...', 1, (255,0,0))
        win.blit(text, (width/2 - text.get_width()/2, height/2 - text.get_height()/2))
    else:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
        text = font.render('Your move', 1, (0,255,255))
        win.blit(text, (80,200))

        text = font.render('Opponents', 1, (0,255,255))
        win.blit(text, (380,200))

        move1 = game.get_player_move(0)
        move2 = game.get_player_move(1)

        if game.both_players_moved():
            text1 = font.render(move1, 1, (0,0,0))
            text2 = font.render(move2, 1, (0,0,0))
        else:
            if game.player1_moved and player == 0:
                text1 = font.render(move1, 1, (0,0,0))
            elif game.player1_moved:
                text1 = font.render('Locked in', 1, (0,0,0))
            else:
                text1 = font.render('Waiting...', 1, (0,0,0))
            
            if game.player2_moved and player == 0:
                text2 = font.render(move2, 1, (0,0,0))
            elif game.player2_moved:
                text2 = font.render('Locked in', 1, (0,0,0))
            else:
                text2 = font.render('Waiting...', 1, (0,0,0))
        
        if player == 1:
            win.blit(text2, (100,350))
            win.blit(text1, (400,350))
        else:
            win.blit(text1, (100,350))
            win.blit(text2, (400,350))

        for button in buttons:
            button.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

buttons = [Button('Rock', 50, 500, (0,0,0)), Button('Scissors', 250, 500, (255,0,0)), Button('Paper', 450, 500, (0,255,0))]
def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    n = Network() # Use the Network() class to connect to the server
    player = int(n.get_player())
    print('You are player', player)

    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        try:
            game = n.send('get')
            # If this doesn't work it'll be because one of the clients have already exited and the game was deleted
        except:
            run = False
            print('Coudn\'t get the game')
            break

        if game.both_players_moved():
            redraw_window(win, game, player)
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
            try:
                game = n.send('reset')
            except:
                run = False
                print('Coudn\'t get the game')
                break
            
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 90)
            if (game.winner() == 1 and player == 1) or (game.winner() == 0 and player == 0):
                text = font.render('You Won!', 1, (255,0,0))
            elif game.winner() == -1:
                text = font.render('Tie Game!', 1, (255,0,0))
            else:
                text = font.render('You Lost!', 1, (255,0,0))
            
            win.blit(text, (width/2 - text.get_width()/2, height/2 - text.get_height()/2))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(2000)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                for button in buttons:
                    if button.click(position) and game.connected():
                        if player == 0:
                            if not game.player1_moved:
                                n.send(button.text)
                        else:
                            if not game.player2_moved:
                                n.send(button.text)
        redraw_window(win, game, player)

def menu_screen():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        win.fill((128,128,128))
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
        text = font.render('Click to Play!', 1, (255,0,0))
        win.blit(text, (width/2 - text.get_width()/2, height/2 - text.get_height()/2))
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                run = False
    
    main()
            
while True:
    menu_screen()
```

### server.py file:

```py
import socket
from _thread import *
import pickle
from game import Game

server = '192.168.100.5' # The server.py script has to be runing on this machine
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)

s.listen(2) # This listen for two clint connections
print('Waiting for a connection, Server Started')

games = {}
id_count = 0

def threaded_client(connection, player, game_id): 
    # Each client has one version of this function running in the background at the same time
    global id_count
    connection.send(str.encode(str(player)))

    reply = ''
    while True: # It runs once for every frame
        try:
            data = connection.recv(4096).decode() # it Receives string from the client

            if game_id in games: 
                # This checks if the game still exists, because if the client disconnects from the game we'll delete it
                game = games[game_id]

                if not data:
                    break
                else:
                    if data == 'reset':
                        game.reset_moves()
                    elif data != 'get':
                        game.play(player, data)
                    
                    connection.sendall(pickle.dumps(game))
            else:
                break
        except:
            break
    print('Lost connection')
    try:
        del games[game_id]
        print('Closing game:', game_id)
    except:
        pass
    id_count -= 1 # One client was closed
    connection.close()

while True: # This runs once for every connection made
    connection, address = s.accept() # connection -> new socket object; address -> address of the sockect from the other device
    print('Connected to: ', address)

    id_count += 1
    player = 0
    game_id = (id_count - 1) // 2 # This will make a single game id for every two people that connect to the server
    if id_count % 2 == 1: 
        # if the result is 0, it means that there are even clients playing the game, but if it is 1,
        # it means that there are odd clients playing the game
        games[game_id] = Game(game_id) # It creates a new game when there are odd clients
        print('Creating a new game...')
    else:
        games[game_id].ready = True
        player = 1

    # start_new_thread(function, arguments)
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (connection, player, game_id))
```

### network.py file:

```py
import socket
import pickle

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = '192.168.100.5'
        self.port = 5555
        self.address = (self.server, self.port)
        self.player = self.connect()
    
    def get_player(self):
        return self.player
    
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.address) # It connects to the server
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode() # It receives a string which is 0 or 1
        except:
            pass
    
    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(str.encode(data)) # It sends a string to the server
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048*2)) # It receives a object from the server
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
```

### game.py file:

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.player1_moved = False
        self.player2_moved = False
        self.ready = False # When True there are two people connected to the same game
        self.id = id # This determines which client plays with which
        self.moves = [None, None] # Rock, paper or scissors
        self.wins = [0,0]
        self.ties = 0

    def get_player_move(self, p):
        # p is 0 or 1 and this function will return the move made by the other player
        return self.moves[p]
    
    def play(self, player, move):
        # Update moves and check which player has already played
        self.moves[player] = move
        if player == 0:
            self.player1_moved = True
        else:
            self.player2_moved = True
    
    def connected(self): # Check if the two player are conected to the game
        return self.ready

    def both_players_moved(self):
        return self.player1_moved and self.player2_moved
    
    def winner(self):
        player1 = self.moves[0].upper()[0] # Get the firt letter of the player move
        player2 = self.moves[1].upper()[0]

        winner = -1
        # Player one wins -> winner = 0
        # Player two wins -> winner = 1
        # Tie = -1

        if player1 == 'R' and player2 == 'S':
            winner = 0
        elif player1 == 'S' and player2 == 'R':
            winner = 1
        elif player1 == 'P' and player2 == 'R':
            winner = 0
        elif player1 == 'R' and player2 == 'P':
            winner = 1
        elif player1 == 'S' and player2 == 'P':
            winner = 0
        elif player1 == 'P' and player2 == 'S':
            winner = 1
        
        return winner
    
    def reset_moves(self):
        self.player1_moved = False
        self.player2_moved = False
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. Do you have a more minimal example which focuses on the problem you are having?

Comment: As a first step, I would remove the `try ... except ...` from the `connect` method of `Network`, likely it is hiding the real problem you are having. I.e. it is catching an exception and returning `None` (`pass`)

Comment: I don't think so because the `self.player = self.connect()` is calling the `connect()` method from the Network class

Comment: It's calling `connect()`, silently passing over an error, and returning `None` implicitly via the `pass`. At a minimum, `except Exception as e:` and `print(e)` so you at least know what's happening.

Comment: Doing what you said the error keeps the same. I think maybe the `connect()` method which should return 0 or 1 isn't returning anything, so the `n.get_player()` from `player = int(n.get_player())` at the `main()`function doesn't get the player number as it should. Overall I think when the server and client are in different computers the server isn't sending the player number (this is at the end of server.py file), but I have no idea what to do

Comment: You would still get the same error but you would also get additional output before your error.

Comment: Now I'm getting "TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected component did not respond
correctly after a period of time or an established connection has failed
because the connected host did not respond"

Comment: So you've confirmed this is a networking issue. This could be a wide variety of issues, such as a port being blocked by your firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allow connection on port 5555 on server computer via firewall.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: @LorenaBezerradeAlmeida depends on which OS you are working. I mean server side OS.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: https://windowsreport.com/open-firewall-ports/
here is good tutorial how to open port on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

This maybe is not the straightforward solution to the issue, but I hope it will help in one way or another.

First, I ran your code on Windows 10(python 3.9.4, pygame 2.0.1) and Ubuntu 18.04(python 3.6, pygame 2.0.1), server was on Linux and it worked just fine. So I agree that there is a network problem, most likely with firewall. Thing to notice here, although in my case it worked with different versions of python, make sure that all packages as well as python are the same on both computers. Try changing the server machine (don't forget to change IP in both `server.py` and `network.py`), try running only server on one and both clients on other machine. As other answer suggested, check ports, maybe this is the first thing you should do.

About the error you are receiving. You are trying to cast value to `int` since you received `None` you get this error. You are calling `n.get_player()` which returns `self.player` and `self.player = self.connect()` in the `__init__` method. Now `connect` method is in try except block. So, before return in `connect` put some prints to see the value of `self.client.recv(2048).decode()` before you return it. Also instead of `pass` in except. Put something like this, to catch the exception which will tell you more about your problem (assuming it is here, and I think it is, and it is connected with the server not returning player number):

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Do this in every place you have pass, until you get to the bottom of it.

Also I would like to point out, I know you are learning from the tutorial, but I would not suggest using `_thread`, but `threading` instead. Take a look at [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568555/thread-vs-threading#:%7E:text=threading%20is%20just%20a%20higher%20level%20module%20that%20interfaces%20thread%20.&text=If%20I%27m%20not%20mistaken,class%2C%20but%20get%20more%20functionality.&text=threading%20module%20provides%20different%20ways,threading.) and documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html) Also this is pretty nice [tutorial](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) on `threading`, I know it is maybe too long but I learnt a lot from it. And after a quick view at your code I think there is no need to put `2` in `socket.listen(2)`, more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen).

As I said in the beginning, this may not resolve issue you are having but I hope you will have some benefit from it.