# How could I stop or delay a Pygame timer, which is linked to an User event?

Tags: python, timer, pygame, clock, tello-drone

I'm new to python, but I'm trying to learn it by myself for a university course.
Therefore I have to program a pygame window that represents a drone fly zone (The drone should fly automated like a search helicopter in a given area and on the window a visual representation of what happens should be displayed...).

[How an older version of the pygame window look's like when the virtual drone flies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xwle.png)

So far so good.

Now I have to link the movements of the game-represented drone with the real Tello drone.
I figured out that using threading for the movement commands to the drone is the way to go when the pygame window should run the whole time.

But now I got stuck because I have to delay the automated movements in pygame in order to wait for the drone flight time and response.

I update the pygame window with a `clock` set to `tick(60)` in the loop of the game (therefore I created a Clock `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` in the initialization of the pygame program), but for the automated drone movements I created an Userevent.
The drone movements is trigger like a Snake game via a Userevent witch should be triggered every second.

Therefor I implemented a timer:

```
self.SCREEN_UPDATE = pygame.USEREVENT

self.screen_update = pygame.time.set_timer(self.SCREEN_UPDATE, 1000).
```

But now I have to delay the automated movements in pygame every time the drone should do a movement. Otherwise, the pygame program run's too fast for the real-world problem.
(The User event gets starter again before the real drone has finished his command)

I also tried to implement break functions for that, but they do not work.

```
   def break_rotation(self):
        print("start waiting")
        self.screen_update.time.wait(2000)
        #self.screen_update = pygame.time.set_timer(self.SCREEN_UPDATE, 2000)
        #pygame.time.wait(2000)
        print("end waiting")``
```

```
   def break_move(self):
        print("start waiting")
        self.screen_update.time.wait(3000)
        #self.screen_update = pygame.time.set_timer(self.SCREEN_UPDATE, 3000)
        #pygame.time.wait(3000)
        print("end waiting")
```

I also tried the comment lines. `pygame.time.wait()`makes the whole pygame wait. But You should still be able to use your keyboard for emergency landings and other stuff.

So I only have to delay the next Userevent, where the hole flypath for the next block / section get's tested for the automated flypath and the program decides to fly forward or should it turn.

Does anyone have an Idear how I could achieve that delay on the timer?
Sadly I also couldn't find some similar problems.

EDIT 1:

@CmdCoder858

I think this code may hold the update back for a couple of seconds.
When using the `and` operator combined with a passed variable.
`if event.type == SCREEN_UPDATE and x == 1:`

I also tried using multiple events but that didn't work probably.
`if event.type == SCREEN_UPDATE and event.type == drone_task_finished:`
Interestingly it ignored the hole and operator this way.

```
import pygame
import threading
import _thread
import time



def task():
    global x
    # placeholder for drone task
    print('Test thread start')
    time.sleep(5)  # simulate delay in the task
    x = x+1
    print('Thread ends')
    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(drone_task_finished))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    x = 0
    drone_task_finished = pygame.USEREVENT  # an integer representing the first user event
    drone_task = threading.Thread(target=task)  # create a thread with a task function
    drone_task.start()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Overview of the Search Area")
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))

    SCREEN_UPDATE = pygame.USEREVENT
    screen_update = pygame.time.set_timer(SCREEN_UPDATE, 1000)

    print('Start event loop')


    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()

            if event.type == SCREEN_UPDATE and x == 1:
                print('Hura Timer paused for 5 sec')
                x = 0
                drone_task = threading.Thread(target=task)  # create a thread with a task function
                drone_task.start()

            if event.type == SCREEN_UPDATE:
                print('Update nach 1sec')

            if event.type == drone_task_finished:  # detect if a drone_task_finished event has been posted
                print('Drone task has finished')
```

But is there any reason not to use `import _thread`?

With that, I could call the function multiple times in new threads.
Therefore I have to change the task function to `def task(threadName):`

Now I could simply use `_thread.start_new_thread(task, ("",))` every time the task should be used later on.

Comment: First off welcome to stack overflow. I'm just trying to make sure I understand your issue. So you're making a game where someone can tell the drone where to fly and the drone flies to that location? And your issue is that it takes time for the drone to fly to said location so you need some way in the game to wait for the drone to finish its flight?

Comment: Yea it's like that. 
First off you can change the room parameters for a given area, seen in the link/picture at the red bars, which indicate the wall. The Drone then flys automated through the given space. The whole area is also splitted in rasters like a normal snake game. Every time the timer sets the Userevent, pygame checks if the drone can fly forward or it has to turn because it is next to the wall. All parameters are set in cm to maneuver the tello drone as the same parameter via ``tello.move_forwar(...cm)``. It takes around 3sec to complete the forward move and 2sec to rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what is sounds like, I would guess you want to wait for an event in another thread whilst keeping the main loop running, in which case I think you should try using `pygame.event.post()` function. This function is apparently thread safe so as long as it is called from a thread that was started after `pygame.init()` it should definitely work. You can create a custom event using the `pygame.event.custom_type()` function, meaning that you can wait for the event to be returned without having to pause the display. Comment below if you have any questions.

Edit:

Adding a code example for clarity:

```
import pygame
import threading
import time


def task():
    # placeholder for drone task
    time.sleep(3)  # simulate delay in the task
    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(drone_task_finished))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    drone_task_finished = pygame.USEREVENT  # an integer representing the first user event
    drone_task = threading.Thread(target=task)  # create a thread with a task function
    drone_task.start()
    print('Start event loop')
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == drone_task_finished:  # detect if a drone_task_finished event has been posted
                print('Drone task has finished')
```

Essentially what is happening here is we are creating a task to be completed, then starting the task and continuing with the event loop. Once the task has finished, it will use the `pygame.event.post` function to tell the main thread that its task has been completed. The main thread can then detect this and proceed accordingly.

Edit 2:
To answer your questions, firstly don't worry about creating an answer to your own question, just editing your original question and mentioning that you have done so in a comment is perfectly fine.

As for using the variable x as a way to delay the execution of another event, this can work but I would recommend keeping x out of the threaded `task` function, and instead modify it when your main thread detects the `drone_task_finished` event. This is much better because you don't have to deal with cross-thread variables, so just put that under the `if event.type == drone_task_finished:` block.

As for using multiple custom events, the reason your code `event.type == SCREEN_UPDATE and event.type == drone_task_finished` returned True is because that statement is correct, and this is due to how you initialised each event type. You essentially used this code:

```
drone_task_finished = pygame.USEREVENT
SCREEN_UPDATE = pygame.USEREVENT
```

However the actual way this should be done is like this:

```
drone_task_finished = pygame.USEREVENT
SCREEN_UPDATE = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
```

This is due to how pygame handles event types. Each type is given an integer value, and the built in types get the values up until a certain point. The pygame.USEREVENT constant is an integer representing the first number that is not reserved for other events. This means that creating a new variable to represent an event in pygame should be the integer pygame.USEREVENT, and the second would have the value pygame.USEREVENT + 1. All of this is explained in more detail [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).

Finally, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578141/11072533), `_thread` is an implementation module that should generally be avoided in favour of the `threading` module, which is what I used in my code. With the threading module, you can create and start a new thread using this code:

```
drone_task = threading.Thread(target=task)
drone_task.start()
```

The `threading.Thread` class also has an optional arguments parameter, meaning it is easy to pass in all the arguments you need to the new thread. You can find more information on how this all works in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects).

Comment: Ok, that sounds like an idea I haven't done yet.
I will give it a try. 
So the key part is kind of outsourcing the whole timer thing so I could start separated events?
I have to figure out how the pygame.event.post() thing works. 
Because I haven't used it before. 
What do you actually mean with "meaning that you can wait for the event to be returned without having to pause the display."
The whole event thing is kind of new to me.

Comment: Well essentially you want the game event loop to keep running even if waiting for something to happen, so instead of blocking the program until whatever you want actually happens you can just check every cycle to see if the task being performed in another thread has been completed.

Comment: so did you mean I have to implement the threading via user events in pygame or should I write a new Event for making the ``SCREEN_UPDATE`` Event wait?
Sadly I'm really nooby to that and I was happy to figure out that to see my pygame window run at the same time as my drone, I have to send the commands via new threads. 
``_thread.start_new_thread(drone_fly, ("",))``
Otherwise, the hole pygame kind of lags, when I use the commands without threading.
    
``def drone_fly(self,threadName):``
        ``self.me.move_forward(int(self.drohn_vision)) ``

Comment: I've edited my answer to show a code example of how I would do this and added a better explaination, which will hopefully out work for you.

Comment: Ok, I think I got your Idea now. I played with your code snippet a bit. But I was not sure how to show you my result, so I answered my question myself with your modified code....

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, that helps me very much.